# Accessing Play Framework Template attributes from separate JS files

Tags: javascript, image, coffeescript, playframework-2.0

I am completely new to the Play Framework and don't consider myself too talented at front end development, so I was having a great deal of trouble with this...

I want to be able to have a button that changes an image's source back and forth.  The images are rather large, so I was thinking of preloading the images in the Javascript, but in order to do that I have to access this `Assets controller` in order to grab the different images from the public `images` directory.  The trouble is I am trying to keep everything neat and want to try to keep the Javascript (in my case I'm using Coffeescript) in separate files.  The problem here is that I can't access this `Assets controller` from the Coffeescript (or any of the values passed from the Java to the template for that matter).  So when I try to change the source of the image, it just gives me a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way in Play to create a global javascript object that has access to reverse routing for controllers, including Assets if you configure that. First read this page:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

After reading, set up your javascript routes to include this resource (see embedded router or router resource in docs):

```
routes.javascript.Assets.at
```

Then you'll be able to access assets throughout your javascript as follows:

```
console.log(jsRoutes);
console.log(jsRoutes.controllers.Assets.at("images/favicon.png").url);
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you!  I was struggling with some problems with adding the statement that the link mentioned: `(implicit req: RequestHeader)`.  But then after just removing it, it compiled and worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Good to hear! Play is really cool in the sense that all your routes and links can be references from compiled code, which makes refactoring much easier later on. Plus there are many other great features. If you have issues, StackOverflow questions usually get answered and also check out the Play google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework.